# Integrality of complex infinite series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a (double-sided) sequence of complex numbers satisfying
$$\sum_{\mathbb{Z}}\vert n\vert\,\vert a_n\vert^2<\infty, \tag1$$
$$\sum_{\mathbb{Z}}a_n\bar{a}_{n+k}=\delta_0(k), \qquad \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}. \tag2$$

**EDIT** (revealing previously withheld information). 
A theorem of Boutet de Monvel and Gabber states that under these conditions, $\sum_{\mathbb Z}n|a_n|^2$ converges to an integer. This proof is high-tech and goes through an analysis of circle-valued functions of the circle to the circle that belong to the Sobolev space $H^{1/2}(\mathbb S^1)$. (The $a_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of the function and the integer is the "degree of the function" - a concept generalizing the classical "winding number" of a function around the unit circle).

> **QUESTION.** 
>   Can you give a proof based on basic complex analysis?

**REMARK.** Condition (1) is an alternative Sobolev space qualification for $f\in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ of $f\in L^2(\mathbb{S}^1)$. Condition (2) ensures that $f$ is circle-valued. The quantity $\sum_{\mathbb Z}n|a_n|^2$ is $(1/2\pi i)\int \bar f(z)\,f'(z)\,dz=(1/2\pi i)\int f'(z)/f(z)\,dz$, which is the winding number in the case that $f$ is differentiable.

**NOTATION.** Here $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the unit circle, $\bar{a}$ is complex conjugation and $\delta_0(k)$ is the Dirac-delta function $\delta_0(0)=1$ and $\delta_0(k)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: When you say "$a_n$ is a sequence of infinite series", do you mean that each $a_n$ is an infinite series? Or did you just mean to say that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is a (double-sided) sequence?

Comment: You're right. I fixed that. Thank you.

Comment: So this is quite an interesting question. Your conditions basically say that $f$ satisfies $|f|=1$ and the quantity you are asking about is $(1/2\pi)\int f'(z)\bar f(z)\,dz$, which at least for differentiable functions is the number of times that the argument of $f(z)$ goes around the circle. I'm not familiar enough with Sobolev spaces to see quickly if this extends to $W^{1/2,2}$. In particular, is there a continuous (in the Sobolev space) path of functions from $f(z)=1$ to $f(z)=z$ with range in the circle?

Comment: If $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty }a_n e^{2\pi i n x}$ then your second condition is troubling me. Essentially it reads $\int_0^1 f(x)\overline{f(x)}e^{-2\pi i k x} \,dx = \delta_0(k)$. But then if $g(x) = |f(x)|^2$ it satisfies $\int_0^1 g(x)e^{2\pi i k x}\,dx = 0$ for all $k \neq 0$. I'm no pro at this but doesn't this imply $g$ and therefore $f$ is constant? particularly $f = 1$ by your normalization conditions?

Comment: @james.nixon: your argument suggests $g=1$ or $\vert f\vert=1$ (see Anthony's comment above, this is okay). But, $\vert f\vert=1$ does not imply $f=1$ for complex functions. Take $f(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @james.nixon: As per your notation, let $f(\theta)=\sum_{\mathbb{Z}}a_ne^{in\theta}$ then condition (2) can be encapsulated as saying $\int_{\mathbb{S}^1}(\vert f(\theta)\vert^2-1)e^{ik\theta}d\theta=0$ for all $k$. This implies $\vert f(\theta)\vert=1$ almost everywhere.

Comment: We agreed that we're talking about functions satisfying $|f|=1$. If the function is differentiable, the result holds. Question: what are continuity properties of functions in your Sobolev space? Can these functions be approximated in the space by differentiable functions? If so, maybe there is a simple proof by approximation?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: They can certainly be approximated just fine, for example by truncated sums $\sum_{|n|\le N} a_n z^n$, or by $\sum a_nr^{|n|}z^n$, but the problem seems to be that the approximating functions won't satisfy $|f|=1$, so it's not obvious (to me) how to pass to the limit in your argument.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: It's clear that you can do an approximation as you suggest. The difference between the approximation and the original function is small in the Sobolev sense. But is it, for example, uniformly small? If it is, you can make it satisfy $|f|=1$ by a real scaling that is close to 1.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Aww yes, how silly of me. I don't know why I went from constant modulus to constant function.

Comment: The smooth functions are dense (even polynomials), so we're not short of approximating functions. As Christian pointed out, the obvious approximants may not do the job. Yet, is it possible to choose a "good" set of estimating functions maintaining the "integrality" property? It's a fair question, though not sure if it easy to achieve this.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Path from $f=1$ to $f=z$? Uhmm ... beside existence of such "paths", we might need homotopy invariance of a sort. BTW, let's hope to keep the proof (if true) to basic complex analysis.

Comment: How "elementary" do you want it to be? You can get away with basic theory of Fourier series and Lebesgue integration, but I'm not so sure about "elementary complex analysis" alone...

Comment: We should try an "elementary as possible", leaving the gauging up to you.

Comment: Then you'd better give us the initial approximation: what is the most elementary proof you know? (there is no need to present full details, a general outline will suffice)

Comment: @fedja: I do not have any suggestion for the elementary proof. Really.

Comment: OK, "the most elementary" was a bad choice of words. It should be "the least non-elementary". I just do not want to waste my and your time by posting something that is more complicated or uses more advanced tools than an argument you know already.

Comment: Please take a look at Christian's "answer" below for the level of existing proofs.

Comment: It is disingenuous to say that no proof has been furnished yet

Comment: I have edited the post to include the information that you withheld in the original posting. I believe this fixes the mistake that you have acknowledged making (I would have expected you to do this yourself).

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed by Anthony in the comments below, the argument I attempted here originally did not hold water.

These issues apparently have been studied quite extensively recently. See for example [J. Bourgain, One cannot hear the winding number.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612192) In particular, in the introduction to this paper, Bourgain mentions that the answer to your question is *yes*; the result is attributed to Boutet de Monvel and Gabber.

Comment: I don't seem to follow where property (3) above has been shown for $h_k$ and they lead to property (3) for $f$.

Comment: Hang on a minute! I agree that $|u(y)-u(x)|$ is comparable to $|g(x)-g(y)|$ on every $A_n$, but the comparison gets worse and worse as $n$ increases. I don't think I believe that there is a $g$ with $|g(x)|<\pi$ that lies in $H^{1/2}$. For a specific example, what if $f(z)=z^2$. Then $g(x)$ should be $g(x)=4\pi x$, except this doesn't take values in $(-\pi,\pi)$. If you force it to take principal values, I think you don't satisfy the integrability condition any more.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: You are right of course.

Comment: This is a spectacular piece of detective work. I wonder if the OP already knew of the existence of this result? (somehow the fact that the question had *exactly the right space* and was asking for an elementary proof suggests this).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Thanks. It *was* detective work, but in the meantime I also received an e-mail from Richard Fournier on this who pointed out many interesting papers on these topics (some by himself).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of some "highbrow" proofs. I wish for an elementary argument (quite original it would be!) because after all the problem I stated in simple terms of infinite series.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: My feeling is the elementary part of this is what Anthony explained in his original comment. We're then still left with a problem about approximation in $H^{1/2}$, which doesn't feel elementary to me, though of course there could be a way around it.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I kind of agree with your assessment. However, we should probably get $H^{1/2}$ out of our minds and consider the problem/solution from a "novel" viewpoint. Maybe.

Comment: So, wait: you knew about the Boutet de Monvel & Gabber work, Amdeberhan, and deliberatley withheld this information when posting the question?

Comment: If the answer to Gerry Myerson's question is "yes" then that is somehow not very professional.

Comment: I thought it would be a distraction to know the complicated methods of proof while we seek for "a basic complex analysis proof". Look, if this bothers everyone then I apologize.

Comment: Yes! This does bother us! Why not say: here is a fact about sequences of complex numbers where the only proof I know goes through high level harmonic analysis (give reference). Does anyone see how to give a more elementary proof?

Comment: I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably true.  Here's a long way to try to prove a special case that was already completely proven in the comments to the OP.

---

Let's wonder what could be said if $a_{j} = 0$ for $j < 0$.  Consider the formal power series $f(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$.  Since $|a_n|$ is summable, $f(z)$ is analytic in $|z| < 1$, and in fact it can be extended to a continuous function on $|z|\leq 1$.  Consider $f(u) \overline{f(v)}$, which has the Taylor series
$$
f(u) \overline{f(v)} = \left(\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n u^n \right) \overline{\left(\sum_{m \geq 0} a_m v^m \right) } = \sum_{n,m} a_n u^{n} \overline{a_m v^m} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n u^{n} \overline{a_{n+k} v^{n+k}},
$$
where we interpret $a_{j} = 0$ if $j < 0$.  This in turn is equal to 
$$
f(u) \overline{f(v)} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \overline{v}^k \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \overline{a_{n+k}} (u\overline{v})^{n}.
$$
Specializing $u=v$ for $|u| = 1$ (or taking limits as $|u| \to 1$) shows
$$
f(u) \overline{f(u)} = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \overline{u}^k \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n \overline{a_{n+k}} = 1.
$$
Thus, we have that $|f(u)| = 1$ for all $|u|=1$ (or rather, view this as a statement about limits).  This implies that $f(u)$ is a [finite Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products), meaning it is of the form
$$
f(u) = c \prod_{i=1} ^{N} \left( \frac{u - r_i}{1-\overline{r_i}u}\right)^{m_i},
$$
where $m_i$ are non-negative integers, $c$ is a constant of modulus $1$ and the $r_i$ are constants of modulus less than $1$.

---

From here, I suspect it might be possible to finish the proof by pushing pretty hard.  Let's see what happens for the first non-trivial case, which is $f(z) = \frac{z-r}{1-rz}$, where $|r|<1$ is a real number parameter.  This has Taylor series
$$
f(z) = -r + \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} z^{n+1} r^n (1-r^2).
$$

So our corresponding sequence will be $$a_{j} = \begin{cases}-r, \qquad &\text{if $j=0$}\\ r^{j-1} (1-r^2), \qquad &\text{if $j> 0$}\\ 0, \qquad &\text{if $j<0$} \end{cases}$$

This sequence satisfies $\sum_{n} n |a_n|^2 < \infty$ (clearly since $|r| < 1$), and $\sum_{n} a_{n}^2 = r^2 + (1-r^2)^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{2n} = 1,$ and for $k > 0$ (which is all we need to check by symmetry) we have
$$
\sum_{n} a_{n} \overline{a_{n+k}} = -r \cdot r^{k-1}(1-r^2) + \sum_{n\geq 0} r^{n}(1-r^2)r^{n+k}(1-r^2) = 0.$$

And we have
$$
\sum_{n} n |a_n|^2 = \sum_{n \geq 1} n (1-r^2)^2 r^{2(n-1)} = 1,
$$
as we wanted.

---

The fact that it works out for this first case is a very positive sign, but not yet a proof.

Comment: No.  Rather, in sentence 3 of my answer, I asked what can be said if $a_j = 0$ for $j< 0$.

Comment: Oh!  So it is.  Nevermind then!